# Is the problem : Determine the number of groups with order $n$ NP-hard?

Tags: group-theory, computational-complexity

It can be hard to determine the number of groups with order $n$, especially for $n=2^k$. So, I wonder, whether there is a polynomial algorithm doing this.

I think, this is not the case because for relatively small numbers $n$, the number of groups with order $n$ is not known.

> Is it known whether this problem is $NP$-hard ?

Comment: In fact, for given $k\gt 3$ the number of groups of order $p^k$ for odd prime $p$ is (so far as I can tell) greater than the number of groups of order $2^k$.

Comment: Are you given the prime factorisation of the order of the group? Otherwise you have to test for primality, and factorise, even for the simplest cases. e.g.  the number of groups of order $pq$ with $p\gt q$ odd primes depends on whether $p\equiv 1\bmod q$ or not.

Comment: @MarkBennet But (to state the obvious) $p^k > 2^k$ for all odd $k$. The available evidence suggests that, for a given $N$, the number of isomorphism classes of groups of order up to $N$ is dominated by the $2$-groups. But I believe we are still a long way away from a proof of that.

Comment: @DerekHolt Of course. I guess my main point is that the complexity of the question is not a simple function of the size of the group.

Comment: @Mark Bennet I assume that the prime factorization is known.

Comment: At a rough guess I would say that it almost certainly is NP-hard, but it is difficult to see how one would go about proving this, and it is unlikely that this question has been specifically investigated. Although it seems totally improbable, it is hard to see how you could actually prove that there is no reasonably simple formula for the number of groups of order $2^k$, say.

Comment: @DerekHolt See Higman's PORC conjecture, which I tripped over while considering this question http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Higman's_PORC_conjecture

Comment: @MarkBennet Yes, I know about the paper by de Sautoy and Vaughan-Lee. I guess you mean this is another example of a situation that seems ridiculously unlikely, but for which it is difficult to see how to go about proving it impossible.